# Versioning css/javascript in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, versioning

I 'm trying to grasp the concept of versioning css/js files.

www.prelovac.com/vladimir/adding-version-to-theme-css-file

---

> ```
> <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/base.css?version=1234" type="text/css" />
> ```
>
> This method will actually prevent the
>   file from being cached, period! This
>   is bad.

[source](http://www.derekville.net/2009/auto-versioning-javascript-and-css-files/)

---

What is the best practice of doing this in Wordpress? I'm confused...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not how it works in my experience. Browsers do cache based on GETs. To test this, go to the author's url (http://static.prelovac.com/style.css?1266235697) with firebug enabled. First request should give you "200 OK", now refresh and you get "304 Not Modified".

[If you're not convinced, you can always try this method](http://particletree.com/notebook/automatically-version-your-css-and-javascript-files/)

Answer (score 3):

There is a plugin up on the WordPress Plugin Repository now that handles versioning of stylesheets and scripts automatically. You can find it at: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/versions/